Staying silent in Aus
According to If applied in the United States, what is the most obvious legally functional difference between the British and American "mirandizing" phrase? and the answers to that question, it may be against your best interest to stay silent when being questioned by the police in the U.K.
Is this the same in Australia, a former Commonwealth colony? Or is the system closer to that of the U.S.?

There is no such thing as 'mirandizing' in the UK. We do have something similar though. 'Miranda rights' are a strictly US thing.

It’s complicated
The right to silence is a fundamental part of Australian common law in every jurisdiction. But it is not a Constitutional right in any jurisdiction so it can be overridden by clear and explicit statute law.
An important limitation of the rule is that it only applies to natural persons, so it cannot be invoked in an investigation against a corporation.
The general rule is that a judge cannot instruct a jury to draw an adverse inference against a defendant if they  use their right to silence (Petty v R 1991 HCA 34) but there are exceptions. Most notably, where the case relies entirely on circumstantial evidence which only the defendant can testify about (Weissensteiner v R 1983 HCA 65), although Victoria has abolished this exception.
In addition, Petty v R held that it was permissible to draw inferences if the defendant answered certain questions but declined to answer others. So, if you are going to invoke your right, do it completely.
In NSW, s89A of the Evidence Act (NSW) allows adverse inferences to be drawn from a failure to mention something which the subject later relies upon in Court and which he/she ought reasonably have been aware of at the time of the questioning. However, they must have been warned of this and they must have a lawyer physically present at the time of the questioning.
In practice, studies have shown that only 5-10% of suspects who are subsequently committed for trial on serious indictable offences invoke their right to silence.
What you must tell the police if asked

Your name and address.
if you are suspected of a drug-related offence, your place and date of birth.
If you are suspected of breaking traffic laws or of having witnessed a collision, police have broad powers to gather information about your involvement and observations.
Specific laws, such as various liquor acts, work health and safety laws, or anti-terrorism acts, make it an offence to refuse to answer questions by the investigator (who are not necessarily police).
All jurisdictions have a corruption investigation commission called by various names. In general, you cannot invoke your right to silence in proceedings they conduct, however, any evidence disclosed is inadmissible in a court.

